# Im learning to code java and i cant figure out why my compiler will not recognize my classes and objects

Tags: java, class

main block

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class pk1 {
public static  void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Enter student name");
    sd mark=new mark();
    Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
    sd.mark.age=15;
    sd.mark.rollnumber=14;
    System.out.println(sd.mark.age);
    System.out.println(sd.mark.rollnumber);





}
```

class that i created

```
}
public class sd {

public static Object mark;
int age;
int rollnumber;


}
```

I clearly stated that sd is the name of the class and declared mark as an object.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Try `sd.age` and `sd.rollnumber`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your **`sd mark=new mark();`** **should be** **`sd mark=new sd();`**.
because **`mark` is not a class, but `sd` is**.

Also access `age` and `rollnumber` using `sd.age` and `sd.rollnumber`

I'll also suggest you to write **little more descriptive class names**. For ex. *renaming* `sd` to `Student`.

Answer (score 2):

This line has an error:

```
sd mark=new mark();
```

`sd` = type (class)
`mark` = variable
`new mark()` -> there is not a "mark" class, it should be `new sd()`, "mark" is a member of the `sd`class

Answer (score 0):

I notice you add your two classes in the same file. You cannot have two public classes in the same file.

I do not know what you wanted to do with the mark attribute in the class sd, but it seems you're learning OOP and you need some clarification about defining classes and instantiating objects.

Remove the mark attribute and the public modifier (if you keep your class definition in the same file). 
Change it for :

```
class Sd {
  int age;
  int rollnumber;
}
```

Then you can create a new instance called mark. Here you instantiate a new mark object, but mark is not a class. To create a new object, use the constructor of the class.

```
Sd mark = new Sd();
mark.age = 15;
System.out.println(mark.age);
```

This should work better. But I will find you some good resources to learn basics of OOP.

Firstly I recommend you to separate your classes in dedicated file. Also it commonly admit that class name starts with a capital letter. That permits an easiest reading of your code.

Comment: i did create a dedicated file. I don't really know how that could be represented here at stack overflow